# 'Cloaked' domain forwarding not working as expected

Tags: html, forwarding, cloaking

I've registered a domain with www.domain101.com. We'll call it www.example.com. I used their 'cloaked forwarding' option on my heroku app, which we'll call example.herokuapp.com. If I want to navigate to the posts index page, I would go to example.herokuapp.com/posts, of course; however, when I try this with my cloaked domain - www.example.com/posts - it takes me to the landing page. What's more, the url is constantly set to 'www.example.com' and the title of each page is "EXAMPLE.COM". I can click buttons on the pages and navigate through my website, but the url remains strictly at 'www.example.com'.

I used the forwarding option available on the website. What else should I be doing?

Comment: I tried to [search Google to see what you mean by "cloaked domain forwarding"](https://www.google.com/search?q=heroku+cloak+forwarding), and this question is the top hit. Do you happen to have a direct link to the Heroku documentation page about what the "cloaked forwarding" is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Domain cloaking uses a frame to make visitors' browsers show the cloaking domain in the location bar, while having the actual content hosted somewhere else. That's why the location bar never changes when you navigate around the site; and it isn't surprising that domain101's cloaking implementation doesn't forward path information to your Heroku app.

What you should do instead is configure a DNS server to direct traffic for your domain directly to Heroku. The simplest option for that on Heroku is the [Zerigo DNS Add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/zerigo_dns), which is free if you're hosting a single domain. You can also find DNS servers provided by lots of other people if you prefer.

Once you've configured a DNS server, you also need to tell your registrar that the DNS server you chose is the primary DNS for your domain. The way to do that varies between registrars, so you should check domain101's documentation for details.